# Trouble with StringTokenizer using two lines of text

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a program that is supposed to take a text file specified in the run arguments and print it one word at a time on separate lines. It is supposed to omit any special characters except for dashes (-) and apostrophes (').

I have basically finished the program, except that I can only get it to print the first line of text in the file.

Here is what is in the text file:

This is the first line of the input file.  It has
more than one line!

Here are the run arguments I am using:

java A1 A1.txt

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class A1
{
   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
   {
      if (args.length > 0)
      {
      String file = (args[2]);

         try
         {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader (file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s = br.readLine();
            int i = 1;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());

            }
               br.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
               System.out.println ("The following error occurred " + e);
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling `readLine()` once! So you are only reading and parsing through the first line of the input file. The program then ends.

What you want to do is throw that in a while loop and read every line of the file, until you reach the end, like so:

```
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

Basically, what this means is *"while there is a next line to be read, do the following with that line".*